# why does result() take no arguments?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class result:
   def _init_(self,phy,chem,math):
           self.phy=phy
           self.chem=chem
           self.math=math
   def printavg(self):
           print(f"average={(self.phy+self.chem+self.math)/3}")

rollone=result(86,95,85)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: result() takes no arguments
```

> getting the same error again and I used *init* constructor in the right way
> is anyone to explain is most welcome and benevolent of you?

Comment: `init` is a double underscore (dunder) function `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `init` is wrong, it is `__init__` and not `_init_`, ie, with double underscores :

```
class result:
   def __init__(self,phy,chem,math):
           self.phy=phy
           self.chem=chem
           self.math=math
   def printavg(self):
           print(f"average={(self.phy+self.chem+self.math)/3}")
```